# Mixed content issue while running updates.php in Drupal 6.37

Tags: updating, security

We are facing this issue again for Drupal version 6.37.
We do not have jquery update module installed.

In our case the progress bar just hangs but the functionality is accomplished.The Drupal core and modules do get updated.
When we run the update.php since ours is a https site, we get the Mixed content error

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com/update.php?op=start&id=14' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://example.com/update.php?id=14&op=do'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Just in case you want to consider it (no obligation): contact me (via https://www.drupal.org/u/pierre.vriens) about your new question from a few mins ago ... PS: I'll delete this comment again after you confirm you saw it (via an extra comment here that you delete soon also?)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I doubt this can be debugged from here. You need to:

1. inspect which elements, exactly, was served over HTTP instead of https.
2. Then, identify what created them (we may or may not be able to help)
3. Fix the reason - most common I know is hardcoding URLs in templates, but it might not be the case for you.

Last but not least, I find it to be much stable to use [drush](http://www.drush.org/) for updates.